# How to download xml file through in php?

Tags: php, xml, fbjs

I created xml file in php.  This file is successfully saved in my server directory.
Now, I want to download this file only through php, not javascript.

How can I save this file?

Comment: You should accept your recent questions.

Answer (score 9):

Try `file_get_contents()` and `file_put_contents()`.

```
<?PHP

$xml = file_get_contents("http://yoursite.com/yourxml.xml"); // your file is in the string "$xml" now.
file_put_contents("/path/to/file/yourxml.xml", $xml); // now your xml file is saved.

?>
```

Comment: $xml = file_get_contents("http://www.abc.com/facebook/developments/abcc/admin/filename.xml"); // your file is in the string "$xml" now.
 file_put_contents("http://www.abc.com/facebook/developments/abcc/admin/filename.xml", $xml); // now your xml file is saved.

Comment: this is not working , if this is wrong can you send me correct.