# How to download multiple files using php from csv as the references?

Tags: php, csv, download

kind of new to php but am starting to get my head around it a little.

What i want to do...

I have a csv which contains references to files that i can download.

I found this page: [How to download xml file through in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154781/how-to-download-xml-file-through-in-php)

This enabled me to download an xml file if i write the url and directory i want to save it to with no problems.

How to i modify this php to get all xml files in my csv?

I assume it will be something like: foreach and variable functions etc but have no idea how.

Also in the csv contains only the file name not the full url, but the first part of the url will always stay the same. 
And same goes for the download directory. I want all the files to be downloaded into the same directory as i pick and the file name will be the same as the one im downloading.

Also how would i change the php if for example i want to now download images, or any other file type? I assume this will be fairly easy?

Thanks for your help
John

Comment: Can you show us what the format of your CSV looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suppose that the CSV file is like the following:

> "Filename";"URL"
>
> "File 1"; "URL to f1"
>
> "File 2"; "URL to f2"
>
> "File 3"; "URL to f3"
>
> "File 4"; "URL to f4"
>
> "File 5"; "URL to f5"
>
> "File 6"; "URL to f6"

So the column separator would be `;` and the string separator `"`

so the code would be something like:

```
<?php

$fileContent = $file("path/to/csv/file"); // read the file to an array
array_shift( $fileContent ); // remove the first line, the header, from the array
foreach( $fileContent as $line ) {
    $columns = str_getcsv( $line, ";", '"' );
    $url = $columns[1]; // as suposed previously the url is in the second column
    $filename = $columns[0];
    downloadFile( $url, $filename );
}

function downloadFile( $url, $filename ) {
    $newfname = "/path/to/download/folder/" . $filename ;
    $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
    if ($file) {
        $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");
        if ($newf)
            while(!feof($file)) {
                fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
            }
    }
    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }

    if ($newf) {
        fclose($newf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this, i will give it a try shortly. Will let you know the results.